# Adding MANY variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, math, tensorflow

If `tf.add` only takes 2 to 3 positional arguments how do I add half a dozen or more values together (hoping you won't say do lots of sub-totals first!). I'd like to specify something like:

```
tf.AddTheseTogether(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5) etc.
```

Tried `tf.add_n` and had same result. It errors with #tf.add or add_n takes 2 to 3 positional arguments no more. Also tried `tf.add([value1,value2],[value3,value4])` etc. Guessing there must be another function? `tf.sum` not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.add_n`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_n) takes a list of inputs, like this (note the `[]`):

```
tf.add_n([value1,value2,value3,value4,value5])
```

Comment: There's also `tf.reduce_sum()` which may be relevant.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much Landogardner and JoshVarty - really much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you :-)